External validation prediction model with missing predictor
I am planning to externally validate a clinical prediction model, developed in one country, using health register data from another country. Until recently, the register data contained all predictor variables required to make predictions using the model (in order to validate it). However, the model has recently been updated to include a variable which we do not have (namely smoking history as a binary variable).
We can still validate the older version of the model (still in widespread use) but is there any way we can still validate the new model? I’m thinking along the lines of using a proxy variable for smoking such as lung cancer diagnosis, or imputation etc. to predict this variable before validation. Would this be better than not validating it at all?
